# How to return any record of any rows with any column matching input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to search up multiple columns at once. For example, given a keyword `apple`, I want to know if it is contained in `title`, `description`, `tag`. Currently I can search and return records from a column, I want to search all columns.

I tried this in my controller class

```
def search
    keyword = params[:input]
    task = Task.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%",  " OR priority LIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%")
    @tasks = task.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)

end
```

And this is my ActiveRecord:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.datetime :due
      t.integer :priority
      t.text :tag

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My model
class Task < ApplicationRecord
enum priority: [:High, :Medium, :Low]

```
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :priority, presence: true
  validates :due, presence: true

end
```

edit: add my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` expects one condition and multiple arguments. That means the SQL statement cannot be split into multiple segments (as a list or as a hash).

Change

```
task = Task.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%",  " OR priority LIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%")
```

to

```
task = Task.where("title LIKE ? OR priority LIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%", "%#{keyword}%")
```

or

```
task = Task.where("title LIKE :q OR priority LIKE :q", q: "%#{keyword}%")
```

See the [Rails Guides about the query interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions).

Comment: it still cannot find my priority thou, is it to do with how priority is a enum?

Comment: Ah, wait. `priority` is an integer column, not a `string`. You cannot use `LIKE` with integer columns.

Comment: hmm how can I search up it's string value?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Imagine there is the integer `12345` do you expect to find it with a query `LIKE %234%`?

Comment: I want the input to be string value and use it to search up the db

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and the value in the DB that it should find?

Comment: like type in "medium" and return a row which contains it

Comment: ` #<Task id: 10, title: "Add column", body: "Add MarkAsCompleted ", tag: "", due: "2020-12-30 08:55:00.000000000 +0000", priority: "Medium", created_at: "2020-12-30 08:59:03.254429000 +0000", updated_at: "2020-12-30 08:59:03.254429000 +0000">`

This is what my row looks like

Comment: The datatype of the `priority` column is `integer`. `integer` columns can only store numbers and do not support `LIKE` queries. Therefore searching the string `LOW` does not makes any sense. Just remove it from your query or change the datatype of the `priority` column to `string`.

Comment: hmm thanks, thought there's a way to search it's stringvalue

Comment: Looks like you are using `enum`. The string representation of an `enum` only exists in Rails, not in the database, In this case, you need to look upfront if the search string matches any named enum and then you need to query by the numbers attached to the matching enums.